# Ignoring some elements/classes in JAXB binding

Tags: jpa, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I use Hyperjaxb to generate some classes with JPA annotations from XML schemas. I'd like to specify which elements from given schema xjc should generate. I can't change xsd file. I can modify only bindings.xjb. I tried to use hj:ignored, but without success.

Answer (score 7):

Well, `hj:ignored` is the [answer](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide#CustomizationGuide-Ignoringclasses). It allows you to make Hyperjaxb ignore certain classes.

Here's an example:

```
    <jaxb:bindings
        node="xsd:complexType[@name='issue121Type']//xsd:element[@name='simpleCollection']">
        <hj:ignored/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Customizations work in schema as well as via `xjb` files.

See [this project](http://java.net/projects/hj3/sources/svn/show/trunk/ejb/tests/issues) for instance.

How does "without success" reveal itself?

Comment: I put this line and still get @Entity etc. There's no any failures like empty element.

Here — http://www.eurocris.org/Uploads/Web%20pages/CERIF2008/Release_1.2/XML-SCHEMAS/cfResPubl-RES.xsd — is xsd file. I want to omit cfResPubl. My bindings file — http://pastebin.com/chtjdfT0 .